# What is the non interaction hit dropdown available in the Tags in Google tag manager?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

By Default while creating a tag, this Non interaction value is set to false . I have gone through some articles but couldnt understand this non interaction hit topic.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Non-interaction events are not accounted for when calculating bounce rate of time metrics. This means that if a visitor views a single page and fires a non-interaction event, the session is still considered a bounce and has a session duration of zero minutes. If the user views a single page but an interaction event is fired, the session is no longer considered a bounce, and the session duration is the time between the pageview and the event.